# Discord.py bot: how would I make my discord bot send me responses to a command that users use in DMs e.g. for a survey?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So, I want to make my discord bot have a command for a survey where if the user says something like "#survey" then the bot will DM them with the question. Then I want to make it so the response (where the user uses a command in DM to respond) will be sent to me via DM by the bot? Is this possible?

I know how to make the bot DM the user when they use the command in the discord server, but its the sending me the response part I can't get my head around.

I'm new to discord.py, but I have scanned through the documentation before asking this to check if i could find anything relevant.

Also this is my first ever question on this website, I just signed up so excuse this if it isn't written very well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the part you're having trouble with is capturing the response.  `discord.py` [overloads the `function(args, *, kwargs)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) syntax for commands, so that a single argument after the `*` is the text of the rest of the message.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot('#')

my_user_id = "<Your ID>"  
# You can get your id through the discord client, after activating developer mode.

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def survey(ctx):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, "What's your name?")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def respond(ctx, *, response):
    owner = await bot.get_user_info(my_user_id)
    await bot.send_message(owner, "{} responded: {}".format(ctx.message.author.name, response))

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.is_private: 
         #If any of the users DM the bot, the bot will send you the message in your DMS
         owner = client.get_member("id_to_send")
         await client.send_message(owner,f"{message.author}": {message.content})
    await client.process_commands(message)
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def survey(ctx):
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.author,"The question you want to ask.")
```

This could work fine :-)