# discord.py Bot does not respond to input in DMs

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: To receive a response from the message author in their DMs with the bot.

**My problem**: Bot does not respond when message is sent to it in the DMs as I am expecting. There are no error messages.

**Code**:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Sending a dm now")
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == discord.channel.DMChannel
    try:
        await ctx.author.send("Say test: ")
        response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if response.content.lower() == 'test':
            await ctx.send("Test successful")
        elif response.content.lower() == 'banana':
            await ctx.author.send("That works too")
    except:
        # do things here
```

**Images**:

[image: No response is given]

(Above image) No response is given despite the given conditions being met.

**References/ Other Questions I have referred to**:

- [Discord.py Check if Channel is a DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987677/discord-py-check-if-channel-is-a-dm)
- [discord.DMChannel API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=dm#discord.DMChannel)
- [Discord.py - Reply to DM with a specific message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63802655/discord-py-reply-to-dm-with-a-specific-message)
- [Discord.py bot: how would I make my discord bot send me responses to a command that users use in DMs e.g. for a survey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496742/discord-py-bot-how-would-i-make-my-discord-bot-send-me-responses-to-a-command-t)

Comment: This part of your check: `message.channel == discord.channel.DMChannel` is what is causing you the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your check, if you print `message.channel` you will get:

```
Direct Message with username#1234
```

And if you print `discord.channel.DMChannel` you will get:

```
<class 'discord.channel.DMChannel'>
```

You will notice they are two different things, changing your check to this should fix the problem:

```
def check(message):
    return message.author == ctx.author and str(message.channel.type) == "private"
```